# Is there a way to filter some fields from Play's CRUD form?

Tags: java, playframework, crud

I'm using this tag in a custom view, to generate a CRUD form for my object:

```
<div class="configForm">
  #{crud.form /}
</div>
```

This generate a CRUD form inside my own view. Is there a way to customize the generated form by removing a few fields that I don't want to be editable?

I spotted this line inside form.html:

```
#{list items:_fields ?: currentType.fields*.name, as:'fieldName'}
```

If I'm reading this right, then there is a `_fields` parameter that might let me opt-in to fields (I prefer opt-out, but I'll take opt-in). How do I use this _fields parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter fields like:

`#{crud.form fields:['name', 'email', 'password']/}`

which will show only the fields name, email and password

Regards
Ronald

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [filtered version](https://gist.github.com/1399990) of CRUD's `ObjectType`. The controller can select which fields to filter, like this:

```
public static void show(long id) {
    MyModel object = MyModel.findById(id);
    CRUD.ObjectType type = new FilteredObjectType(MyModel.class, 
        "filteredField1",
        "filteredField2");
    render(type, object);
}
```

Comment: @Stefano - well, technically when I posted this I wanted to `filter out` fields, and not have to explicitally write a list of the fields I do want. Still, it's close enough, and perhaps more useful than opting out. I'll accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/crud#objecttype). Then you can easily write your own ExtCRUD class which ignores all fields which are declared in a static variable of your Controller. How ever FilteredObjectType is for special cases the easier solution.